# Best UI display of a company's product name with logo containing words for accessibility

Tags: accessibility, logos, ux-writing, heading

I am working on company's product where the name of the product will show in many views in the UI.
The product's name has a logo with words only.
The logo is small 20 -20px and and contains part of the product name. With the name in text on the same line as the logo - the name essentially repeats.

I'd like to know the best practice for both ux and accessibility.

For privacy here is an example of the heading that will display on many ui views:

Mock example 1.

`[logo that says richards creditplus] Richard's CreditPlus financing`

In the above the logo says the same thing as the text line beside it.

Mock example 2
( just has the logo to be read and the text leaving out the words in the logo. )

`[logo that says richards creditplus] Financing`

In the above , if the user *reads* the logo and the word left to right , the name does not repeat. However, a logo is a visual symbol representing the object, so the user is not necessarily *reading* what it says but recognizing what it is symbolizing. Does it matter if the first example essentially is repeating?

I hope this makes sense, and I'm happy to clarify any questions.

Answer (score 1):

[A11y.com](https://a11y.com) has an interesting way of handling this.

Here's what their navigation and logo look like to sighted users:

[image: a11y screenshot of logo and nav]

And here's the code behind that:

```
<nav role="navigation" id="navigation-wrap">
<div class="container" style="height:100px; position:relative;">
    <div class="logobox"><A href="/home/" title="Visit Homepage"><img src="/image/mainlogo.png" class="mainlogo" title="Logo"></A></div>
    <ul id="navigation">
        <li><a href="/home/" class="active">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="/headings/" >Headings</a></li>
        <li><a href="/imagealts/" >Images</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The logo does not use an alt attribute because it is telling the screen reader to treat it like a link via the "Visit Homepage" title in the  tag.

The graphic portion of your logo could be handled the same way (as a "Visit Homepage" link), while the name of the product/company can still read out.

Comment: Thank you. We are creating a label for a product within a product. The image in the object will not link to anything. I'm wanting to know more about if words need to display next to a logo that contains the same words in it for readability of the label of the product. Especially if the logo is quite small, i.e. 20-24px height.

Comment: This looks like lazy coding to me. Sighted users get visual confirmation that they are on the correct website but non-sighted users get a duplicated home button instead?! There is no alt attribute on the image to tell non-sighted users what should be there. There are no title attributes on the navigational links... This is neither good UX nor good accessibility.

Comment: Imo does not look good to me. As per WCAG 2.5.3 Label in Name (WCAG 2.1 Level A) the IMG here should have `alt="a11y"`

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is something for the logo designer to fix, not a UX issue. Anyway, here are some generic ideas. Analyzing the real case, surely there are more options.

---

Usually, a logo has a descriptive tagline. As described in the question, the case is a bit particular since the tagline is the content of the logo itself, so it would be necessary to resort to some graphic resource to avoid repeating the name in the same place.

The first thing that comes to mind is to separate the description from the logo itself. In a web design, there's enough space to be able to give importance to each element and hide repetitions, it's just a matter of finding a good location so that each element stands out as its own entity within the content:

[image]

Even that description can be a corporate element, for example recovering some of the basic colors or shapes of the logo.

[image]

If none of these options are viable, another alternative is to disguise the text so that the repetition is not so obvious, be creative with the tagline:

[image]

Anyway, being the logo so small, 20 x 20 px, I don't think the repetition is so noticeable. Personally, I would be careful not to use the same font to show that despite being the same, they are two different elements.